# PHP encrypting of a password

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I want to store encripted password and login to database and then to retrieve it and check the validity of user inputs. I must have misunderstood something functamental about crypt function because my very simple script is not working. Here it is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
     mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect mysql server');
       mysql_select_db('ChemAlive_login')  or die('cannot connect database');

$user_input='test';
$mail='test@test.com';

 $password = crypt($user_input);

  $q=mysql_query("select * from login where mail='".$mail."' ") or die(mysql_error());
  $n=mysql_fetch_row($q);
 if($n>0)
{
  $q=mysql_query("select password  from login where mail='".$mail."' ");
  $pp=mysql_fetch_row($q);
  if(crypt($user_input,$pp[0])==$pp[0]) echo "ok";
  else echo "wrong";
}
else
{   $insert=mysql_query("insert into login values('".$mail."','".$password."')") or die(mysql_error());
echo "insert";}
?>
```

Atthe first execution test login and email are inserted and "insert" echo shows. But on the second run I have "wrong" echo and I don't understand why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use crypt, why not use md5, or better still sha1? That would mean re-writing your code as follows, using sha1:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/plain");
 mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect mysql server');
 mysql_select_db('ChemAlive_login')  or die('cannot connect database');

 $user_input='test';
 $mail='test@test.com';

 $password = sha1($user_input);

 $q=mysql_query("select * from login where mail='".$mail."' ") or die(mysql_error());
 $n=mysql_num_rows($q); //not mysql_fetch_row, as that does not return count but an array
 if($n>0)
 {
  $q=mysql_query("select password  from login where mail='".$mail."' ");
  $pp=mysql_fetch_row($q);
  if(sha1($user_input)==$pp[0]) {
    echo "ok";
  }
  else {
   echo "wrong";
  }
}
else
{   
 $insert=mysql_query("insert into login values('".$mail."','".$password."')") or die(mysql_error());
echo "insert";
}
?>
```

NOTES:

1. Consider using mysqli_* functions rather than mysql_* functions, as these are deprecated.
2. Your code currently is subject to a number of security vulnerabilities, especially since your values are not escaped.
3. Is there a particular reason for setting your content type to text/plain? This is a PHP script.

Comment: I am getting "wrong" echo with that to. I don't understand how that's possible.

Comment: if(sha1($user_input)==$pp[0]) echo "ok"; else echo "wrong"

Comment: check the size of your password column in your database, that is the length of the column. sha1 strings are 40 characters long. Ensure your database password column can hold up to 40 characters, otherwise the password will be truncated and some characters will be lost.

Comment: That was that! password column too small! I kind of feel stupid. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This will help (cant recommned php.net enough):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

You may have problems because you have no second argument.

> **salt**
>
> An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the
>   behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to
>   unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks but it is where I started from and I still can't figure the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should change the

```
if(crypt($user_input,$pp[0])==$pp[0])
```

to

```
if(crypt($user_input)==$pp[0])
```

You tried to use the `$pp[0]` as the salt for the crypt function. The salt is what determines the encryption algorithm. As you left this argument empty on the passwort that has been inserted, the crypt function automatically used MD5 to encrypt.